# Filter the Field Type Entity data

Tags: 2sxc

I have a Content-Type with a Fieldtype Entity to select one or more articles for a List of featured articles.

Is it possible in 2sxc to filter the results of the Fieldtype Entity by the data of the Entity, e.g. all for country = "Germany" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ and code it, or you can use the visual query designer using the Relationship filter. As of now, the visual query can only work on the primary property (title), but that will change soon.